# Twitter API - Show Latest Tweet of Multiple Specified Users

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm wondering if I can show the latest Tweet of multiple Twitter users specified by me.

This is what I have *with the keys removed, they are indeed defined in my actual code*:

```
<?php
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
    'consumer_key' => "",
    'consumer_secret' => ""
);

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';
$getfield = '?user_id=McDonalds,Wendys,Dominos&count=1';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest();

echo '<pre>';
$response = var_dump(json_decode($response));
```

But it only outputs my latest Tweet. How can I make it so it outputs the latest Tweet of the specified users?

Comment: "GET statuses/user_timeline" will return tweets for one specific user. And you confound user_id and screen_name. So i think you shloud send a request for each user. See : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this - neither is quite as simple as you want.

Firstly, you could request the user timeline for each user individually.

So call `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=McDonalds` and then `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=Wendys` and so on.

That might be slow.  So, alternatively, you could [create a list](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/twitter-lists) with all the users you want to follow.

Then you can [use the List API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/create-manage-lists/api-reference/get-lists-statuses) to get all the recent tweets of those users.